# How to pick recently inserted record id of the current session?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, asp.net-4.0

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 with SQL Server 2008 R2 and PetaPoco ORM.

A Web Form consists of Tab Panels, for example:

-- Employee General Information

-- Appointment

-- Education

Each Tab Panel entry goes to a specific table in SQL Server. I have a main table, employee, with Primary Key empID. Other tables, viz., appointment, education etc. are related with empID.

I have multiple methods to Save record in respective tables:

**AddGeneralInformation** saves the General Information Tab Panel record.

**AddAppointment** saves the appointment details and so on.

The application is being used in a concurrent environment where multiple users are either inserting or updating records.

For the second and third methods to insert a new record, the methods must have the correct empID. As soon as the first method (General Information) saves the record, the empID is to be used in other methods.

The problem is that if I use:

```
Select max(empID)
```

then it won't pick the correct empID as many users are inserting records.

On solution I feel is to use another column containing SessionID and use this query:

```
Select max(empID) where sessionID = SessionID
```

Is there any more reliable way to do this?

** Edited **

```
   protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Add("TaskFlag", "New");
        AddUpdateEmployee();
        AddUpdateAddress();
    }

protected void AddUpdateEmployee()
{
    var db = new PetaPoco.Database("cnWeb");   
    var emp = new employee();                  */


    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        db.BeginTransaction();

        emp.deptcode = txtEmpCode.Text.TrimEnd();
        emp.empname = txtEmpName.Text.TrimEnd();
        emp.guardianname = txtGuardian.Text.TrimEnd();
        emp.relationwithemployee = ddlRelation.Text.TrimEnd();
        emp.gender = ddlGender.SelectedItem.Text;
        emp.dateofbirth = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDOB.Text.TrimEnd());

        if (Session["TaskFlag"].ToString() == "New")
            db.Insert(emp);
        else if (Session["TaskFlag"].ToString() == "Update")
            db.Update<employee>("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE empid = @0", Session["EmployeeID"]);

        reuse.CustomClientMessage("Record Saved", this.Page);
        ClearFields();
        /* Commit Transaction */
        db.CompleteTransaction();
        scope.Complete();
    }
}


protected void AddUpdateAddress()
{
    var db = new PetaPoco.Database("cnWeb");    
    var addr = new emp_address();

    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        db.BeginTransaction();

        /* Permanaent Address */
        addr.perm_houseno = txtPermHouse.Text.TrimEnd();
        addr.perm_street = txtPermStreet.Text.TrimEnd();
        addr.perm_place = txtPermCity.Text.TrimEnd();
        addr.perm_pincode = txtPermPincode.Text.TrimEnd();
        addr.perm_landlinephone = txtPermLandline.Text.TrimEnd();
        addr.perm_mobilephone = txtPermMobile.Text.TrimEnd();

        if (Session["TaskFlag"].ToString() == "New")
            db.Insert(addr);
        else if (Session["TaskFlag"].ToString() == "Update")
            db.Update<emp_address>("SELECT * FROM emp_address WHERE empid = @0", Session["EmployeeID"]);

        /* Commit Transaction */
        db.CompleteTransaction();
        scope.Complete();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution: make your `EmpID` column an `INT IDENTITY` in SQL Server and let the database handle the details.

Anything you dream up in code (T-SQL or C#) is most likely going to have some issues and won't work well under load - why not just use what's there, works, and is tested by hundreds of thousands of users?

Once you insert a row into a table with an `INT IDENTITY` column, you can fetch that value using

```
DECLARE @NewEmpID INT
SELECT @NewEmpID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

or alternatively, you could use the `OUTPUT` clause on your `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableHere(List of columns)
OUTPUT Inserted.EmpID
VALUES(list of value here)
```

Comment: As marc_s says ^ then return scope_identity - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: @marc_s It is already an IDENTITY column. I check the link, but the statements are not in the same scope. I am using ORM. Check OP for code samples.

Comment: @RPK: great - then just use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` after the `INSERT` (or the `OUTPUT` clause) to get the **actually inserted** `EmpID` instead of trying to "guesstimate" it using something like `max(empid)` (totally unreliable, as you've noticed yourself)

Comment: Well, it that case - PetaPoco *should* automatically update the saved entity, so that you can read out the `EmpID` given - at least the various ORMs I know do that...

Comment: @marc_s At least I need to provide the empID to tell PetaPoco which row I want to update?

Comment: Yes - but what I'm trying to say: when you save the new employee and the row gets inserted into the employee table, PetaPoco should have a mechanism to tell you what the new `EmpID` for that inserted row is - so you should get that information right away - without having to go trying to figure it out yourself

Comment: @marc_s Will check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

create a new column like `created_date`with datetime in the table Employee General Information and get the latest record.

Try this Procedure

```
create Procedure Get_LastRow
```

`(`

`-- Table name to retrieve last record`

`@Tname Varchar(50)`

`)`

`AS`

`BEGIN`

```
EXECUTE ('DECLARE GETLAST CURSOR DYNAMIC FOR SELECT * FROM ' + @Tname)
```

`OPEN GETLAST`

`FETCH LAST FROM GETLAST`

`CLOSE GETLAST`

`DEALLOCATE GETLAST`

`END`

Execute the procedure like this.

```
EXEC Get_LastRow 'dbo.TableA'
```

Comment: I am already using a similar approach, but it is just an overhead.

Comment: This Cursor will help you to get the last inserted row `DECLARE GETLAST CURSOR DYNAMIC FOR SELECT * FROM tableName ` `OPEN GETLAST ` `FETCH LAST FROM GETLAST ` `CLOSE GETLAST ` `DEALLOCATE GETLAST`

Answer (score -1):

Just after the Insert query, you the **SELECT @@IDENTITY**. You field EmpID need to be a IDENTITY TO work.

Comment: I would also recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: -1 @@IDENTITY will potentially return an incorrect id if two concurrent insert statements are running.